# In collaborative Word, see just my changes?

Tags: microsoft-word, collaboration

A couple dozen of my co-workers and I are editing the same large Word document.  It pretty regularly happens that, when I try to save my changes to the server, Word tells me that something has gone wrong, and that I can't.  My only options then are either to save my changes locally, or abandon them and start over.

If I do save my changes locally, my next question is, how can I easily identify them?  If there were just one or two I can probably remember, but usually there's at least one I don't. I can do a comparison between my locally-saved copy and the version currently on the server, but that will show my changes interspersed with potentially hundreds of changes made in the meantime by my co-workers.  The last time I tried this, it was impossible to find my changes, and I gave up.

What I want to do is compare my locally-saved changes to *the version of the document as it was the last time I checked it out*.  But there doesn't seem to be a way to do that.  Am I missing something?

Also, P.S., I know I'm supposed to say which version of Word I'm using, but I honestly don't know.  It's pretty new, new enough that the Help menu with its About... choice has disappeared, and I can't seem to find a way to find which version it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Review tab, then go to Tracking and select Track changes.

- Any deletion marked in Strikethrough.
- Any addition underlined.

*Note: By default, Tracking changes are not enabled in Microsoft word by default. You have to manually enable it using the above step(s).*

**Showing only your edits**

Then next Track changes, click Show Markup. Hover on Specific people and unselect every reviewers except you. Then click Accept and click Accept All Changes Shown.   Now only your edits will be marked up.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.  I didn't know about that filter on Show Markup.